# getid() function starter code check php

Tags: php

I was given this starter code by my professor but I only have a vague idea about it. I just hope that someone could check the comments are right.

```
function getID()
{
    $file_name = 'ids';
    if(!file-exists($file_name)) //file exists
    {
        touch($file_name); //picks which file is modified
        $handle = fopen($file_name, 'rt'); //open the file
        $id = 0;
    }
    else //doesn't exists
    {
        $handle = fopen($file_name,'rt'); //pick file to be modified
        $id = fread($handle,filesize($file_name)); //reads the open file
        settype($id,"integer");
    }
    rewind($handle);//Set file pointer to 0
    fwrite($handle,++$id); //

    fclose($handle);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: What is mode `rt`? It isn't documented in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). Do you mean `r+`?

Comment: "Windows offers a text-mode translation flag ('t') which will transparently translate \n to \r\n when working with the file."

Comment: do not open a file read-only if you plan to write. why don't you provide some context on what this is supposed to achieve ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet The function above generates a unique id for one record. The unique id allows you to easily identify a
record to modify or delete or create a relationship between records in different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code with some corrections and the right comments:

```
function getID()
{
    $file_name = 'ids';
    if(!file_exists($file_name)) { // if file doesn't exist 
        touch($file_name); // creates an empty file
        $handle = fopen($file_name, 'wt'); // open the file
        $id = 0;
    } else { // if the file exists
        $handle = fopen($file_name,'wt'); // open the file
        $id = fread($handle,filesize($file_name)); //reads the open file
        settype($id,"integer");
    }
    rewind($handle);//Set file pointer to 0
    fwrite($handle,++$id); // writes the id incremented by one in the file

    fclose($handle); // closes the file
    return $id; // returns the id written in the file
}
```

Comment: you did not open the file with the right mode, these should be `'wt'` and `'r+t'`